# error 1026 error writing file 'mysql-bin'

Tags: mysql

When I want to add/delete/update a record from a remote mysql table and I get this error:

> error 1026 error writing file 'mysql-bin' (errno: 0 : "Internal
>   error/check (Not System Error))

I googled and I see just the description of the error but not the solution. Anyone knows it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently was a server issue. Tech support reset it and everything works fine now. May be they had a memory issue.